# Change status on completed orders

Tags: magento-2.1

It seems that by default it is not possible to change the order status after creating an invoice and status has changed to "Complete".

Is there some way to change the status any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using observer . so create a custom module and create method in observer to generate invoice automatically and also for status change.